# How can i dynamically render nested objects?

Tags: react-native

I would like to render each of my objects inside a Scrollview. 
I need to be able to acces each values of every single objects, ObjectID included.

I tried the following code, but it only returned the ObjectID of the first object.

Any clues ? thank you.

```
for (let result in this.state.results) {
        console.log(result)
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>{JSON.stringify(result)}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is Javascript basics.

You are terminating your loop in first run.
If you need to render all your results you can try using array.map in Javascript.

```
    this.state.results.map(e => {
        console.log(result)
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>{JSON.stringify(result)}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    });
```

Comment: map only works on Arrays, my state contains nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

Return an array of JSX, using `Object.entries()`.
Note that you need to specify a key prop for each entry in the array when rendering using an array. In this case, since each key in an object is unique, I've used the object key.

```js
return Object.entries(this.state.results).map(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key, value)
  return (
    <View key={key} style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{key}</Text>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(value)}</Text>
    </View>
  )
})
```